# #codeigniter $this->input->post();

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm doing a simple form that update user data. I made a form with an hidden input for send the user to the form, until here all it's ok, I can find my `$this->input->post('userid');` Now in the forum there's another hidden input `name="userid"` but when I submit the form I lost it. It's a very stupid stuff, but I'm going crazy. Some can help? Thanks

View

```
<div id="home" class="tab-pane col-md-9 fade in active "><div class="row bordo spazio">
  <p><strong><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Modifica dati</strong></p>
    <hr/>
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
  <div class=" well">
        <?php $attributes = array("name" => "signupform");
        echo form_open("modificacollaboratore/index", $attributes); ?>

        <legend><h3>Modifica dati</h3></legend>
      <label for="titolo">Titolo</label>
        <div class="form-group">
           <div class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio" name="titolo" value="Signor" checked> Signor </div>
           <div class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio" name="titolo" value="Signora"> Signora </div>
           <div class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio" name="titolo" value="Ditta"> Ditta </div>
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('titolo'); ?></span>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" name="userid"  type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('userid'); ?>" />
      </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fname">Nome</label>


            <input class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="<?php $fname; ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $fname;//echo set_value('fname'); ?>" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('fname'); ?></span>
        </div>          

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lname">Cognome</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="lname" placeholder="<?php //echo $lname; ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $lname; //echo set_value('lname'); ?>" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('lname'); ?></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="via">Via</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="via" placeholder="" type="text" value="<?php echo $uvia;//echo set_value('via'); ?>" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('via'); ?></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cap">CAP</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="cap" placeholder="" type="text" value="<?php echo $ucap //set_value('cap'); ?>" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('cap'); ?></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="citta">Città</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="citta" placeholder="" type="text" value="<?php echo $ucitta;//set_value('citta'); ?>" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('citta'); ?></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="teleditta">Telefono ditta</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="teleditta" placeholder="" type="text" value="<?php echo $uteleditta; //set_value('teleditta'); ?>" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('teleditta'); ?></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cellulare">Cellulare</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="cellulare" placeholder="" type="text" value="<?php echo $ucellulare; //set_value('cellulare'); ?>" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('cellulare'); ?></span>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="subject">Valido dal</label>
            <input type="date" name="valido" value="<?php echo $uvalido//set_value('valido'); ?>" style="width:100%">
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('valido'); ?></span>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Modifica</button>
            <button name="cancel" type="reset" class="btn btn-info">Cancella</button>
        </div>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>


<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane col-md-9 fade">
  <h3>Provvigioni</h3>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane col-md-9 fade">
    <div class="row bordo spazio">
    <p><strong><i class="fa fa-handshake-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Partners Commerciali</strong></p>
    <hr/>
    <p><a href="aggiungi"><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i> Nuovo collaboratore</a></p>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="menu3" class="tab-pane col-md-9 fade">
  <div class="row bordo spazio">
    <p><strong><i class="fa fa-address-card-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Clienti</strong></p>
    <hr/>
    <p><a href="intervista"><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i> Nuova intervista</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
  <div id="menu4" class="tab-pane col-md-9 fade">
  <h3>Documenti</h3>
  <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
</div>
  <div id="menu5" class="tab-pane col-md-9 fade">
  <div class="row bordo spazio">
        <p><strong><i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Profilo</strong></p>
        <hr/>
        <p><i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $uname; ?></p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $uemail; ?></p>
          <p><a href="modifica"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Impostazioni</a></p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here $this->input->post('userid') works, but after the data are updated,the form it's empty.
Maybe my english it's too bad, maybe pcs can help to explain the issue
[before submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1De8B.png)

[after submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9V4G.png)

Comment: You can't submit two same-named inputs (except for names with `[]`

Comment: only one input field contain one name. No Duplicates allowed. ***another hidden input name="userid"***

Comment: Please post your form here, that will help others to answer your question efficiently.

Comment: Remember, this is not Instagram or FB. Please maintain the quality of the question.

Comment: @RenjithVR what this suppose to do with Instagram and FB??

Comment: read this [Forms in HTML documents - W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)

Comment: I know you think that I'm stupid. It's a stupid problem but no so stupid

Comment: #Renjith VR but did you understand the question?

Answer (score -1):

Two input in a form cannot have same names except the names are in array. So, always the first input value is picked.

Comment: Sorry maybe my english it's not clear, I meant that I have 2 form :